# How to know what entities has been flushed afterFlush (scheduledForSynchronization)

Tags: doctrine-orm, event-handling

I want to do an action after inserting/updating/deleting some kinds of Entities but only when the change is effective in database, well committed.

> onFlush

When listening the `onFlush` event, I obviously have access to the scheduled entities for insertions, updates and deletions like this:

```
$em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions();
$em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityUpdates();
$em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityDeletions();
```

But this is too early because the transaction is not yet commited...

> postFlush

When I listen the `postFlush` event, I don't have any scheduledEntityInsertions because it already have been done (so it's no more scheduled) and I can't know what objects were flushed.

> scheduledForSynchronization

After having digged, I noticed that there was a `private` property named `scheduledForSynchronization` which has the wanted informations. Unfortunately, it's private.

I wonder why this property is private or why it doesn't exist any getter for it (?).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There are a number of post events: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

Comment: Thank you but that does not help, I know all these events and I need to trigger an action only when some specific entities are flushed and when they are effectively done.

Comment: The only solution I can imagine for now is to have state full subscriber which will remember between `onFlush` and `postFlush` the flushed entities

Comment: Yep.  Looks like you need something very specific.